# Is there a practical way to render modified scaffolding templates without restarting in Grails 3?

Tags: grails, scaffolding, sitemesh

I added code which I thought would do the job, but it looks like `GrailsLayoutView` is somehow interfering with it.

I have a plugin with the following code:

```
def watchedResources = "file:./src/main/templates/scaffolding/*.gsp"

void onChange(Map<String, Object> event) {
    applicationContext.getBean("jspViewResolver").innerViewResolver.generatedViewCache.clear()
}
```

This seems to do what I expect and the `ScaffoldingViewResolver` regenerates the view rather than pulling it from its cache.  The correctly rendered view then is passed up, but it looks like `GrailsLayoutView.renderTemplate` calls `obtainContent` which returns the original content of the scaffolded view rather than the updated content.  It then uses the wrong content in the call to `decorator.render` and all hope of seeing the updated template is lost.

For anyone familiar with this code, am I correctly interpreting the problem and do you know of some way I can get past this?  I have some complex scaffolding templates that I would like to work on, but I'm going to give it up if I have to shutdown grails every time I make a change.

Thank you.